# Is there a way to specify a textblock style which takes a given font color/brush and reduces its saturation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styling

I would like to keep a predefined style from a theme which defines the color of a textblock, but modify this color by just decreasing its saturation.

Basically if the original color was black, it want the new color to be dark grey.

This has to be done dynamically, as the original color of the text will vary and is not fixed to black.

My best guess was to use a style which uses the original `ForeGround` property of the Textblock and runs it through a converter.

```
<Style x:Key="InlineDescriptionStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground, Converter=SaturationReducer}"/>
</Style>
```

However this yields the following error:

```
Error MC3029: 'Foreground' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name. (12, 39)
```

Comment: You could apply a desaturation `ShaderEffect`, as shown here https://iralukhezo.com/2011/03/12/saturationdesaturation-with-hlslpixel-shaders-and-wpf/

Comment: Another "cheap" option is to place the `TextBlock` and a `Border` control inside a `Grid` so that they overlap.  Give the `Border` a `Background` of white with an alpha value.  This can give a reasonably close approximation of desaturation, depending on your specific requirements.  You can set `IsHitTestVisibile` to `false` if you want the `TextBlock` to still respond normally to events.

Comment: @BradleyUffner while the transparent border sounds like a great solution it is unfortunately not applicable to my problem. I am using a shared style for all the TextBlocks which prevents me from changing their position in the visual tree.
I will have a look at the ShaderEffect and update you how it goes.
Thank you already very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after playing around with the shaders I came up with a solution which is so simple it is almost sad:

By using the `Opacity` property of the `TextBlock`/`FrameworkElement` I was able to get the desired effect.

```xml
<Style x:Key="InlineDescriptionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
</Style>
```

Here an image of the final result:
[image]